# Load() seems to lose scope after it's been evoked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, load

I have a button that fades in some html file, and then a back button that returns the user to initial view. However this only works once. They are unable to click the button again for a more detailed view.

```
$('.support').click(function () {
$('.main-view').fadeOut('slow', function () {
    // Animation complete.
    $('.main-view-wrapper').load('includes/modules/support.html');
});
});


$('.back').click(function () {

$('.return-main').fadeOut('slow', function () {
    // Animation complete.
    $('.main-view-wrapper').load('includes/modules/main-view.html');
});
});
```

Comment: Look at the jQuery documentation for `unload()` - http://api.jquery.com/unload/

Comment: `.main-view-wrapper` sounds like an ancestor of `.main-view`, if that is the case `.main-view` will be destroyed `$('.main-view-wrapper').load('includes/modules/support.html');`. Does `includes/modules/main-view.html` have a `.main-view`?

Comment: no .main-view is an ancestor of .main-view-wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `.back` element is generated dynamically, you should delegate the event:

```
$('.main-view-wrapper').on('click', '.back', function(){
    $('.return-main').fadeOut('slow', function () {
         // Animation complete.
         $('.main-view-wrapper').load('includes/modules/main-view.html');
    });
})
```

---

```
$(document).on('click', '.support', function () {
   $('.main-view').fadeOut('slow', function () {
       // Animation complete.
        $('.main-view-wrapper').load('includes/modules/support.html');
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '.back', function(){
    $('.return-main').fadeOut('slow', function () {
         // Animation complete.
         $('.main-view-wrapper').load('includes/modules/main-view.html');
    });
})
```

Comment: This is if the button is being loaded into the content.  To be fair, we don't know where these buttons are located.

Comment: The back button is inside the include file that was loaded via the load() Both the buttons work, but only once. If the user hits back button the main content is shown again but they are unable to then initiate the ajax load. I notice if I paste the code in to firebug it works again, but only once.

Comment: on() looks like it would work, but I'm not sure how to refactor my script to include the on() method

Comment: I tired using the on() like in the above example but that's still not working. It will work once, but after the user navigates back they can't move forward again.

Answer (score 0):

After you've clicked both buttons, you've faded out both `.main-view` and `.return-main`, but you never fade them back in.  So nothing will happen on the next click.  Do you need to fade them in on click of the opposite button?

Comment: When they click the buttons it loads an html file with those elements present, so they are brought back into the dom. I can see that they are showing up in firebug.

Comment: hmmm... any chance you can set up a demo on http://JSFiddle.net, http://JSBin.com, http://codepen.io, or some such?